# PowerShell: an elegant way to create closures

Tags: .net, powershell, closures

[Keith Hill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153982/keith-hill) explained me that [blocks in PowerShell are not closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827561) and that to create closures from blocks I have to call method [.GetNewClosure()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.scriptblock.getnewclosure%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Is there any elegant way to create closures from blocks? (e.g. create a wrapping function, an alias?, ...)

Example:

```
{ block }
${ closure } # ???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a function that takes a scriptblock, calls GetNewClosure and returns the closure.  It is essential that you call this function using the dot operator e.g.:

```
function =>([scriptblock]$_sb_)
{
    $_sb_.GetNewClosure()
}

function A($block) 
{
    B (. => {Write-Host 2; &$block})
}

function B($block) {Write-Host 1;&$block}

A {Write-Host 3}
```

Not sure this is much better than just calling GetNewClosure() on the scriptblock though.  Note you can pick some other name for the function.  I was going for something more like C# lambdas.

Comment: Thx. Why I need to use dot operator to call the function? (To get the same context?)

Comment: Yes, so the function executes within the same scope it is called from.

Comment: Keith, we really need to beat bruce and jeffrey into coming up with a more natural syntax. I hate the GetNewClosure() method. It's so clumsy. I was thinking using double braces: {{ $ix }} ?

Comment: Please, not `{{...}}`. This is a script block that returns a script block. This is a valid scenario. I use it in my practice.

Answer (score 2):

These links might be of some help they talk about closures in PowerShell 2.0

- http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2009/03/27/get-closure-with-getnewclosure.aspx
- http://www.nivot.org/2009/03/28/PowerShell20CTP3ModulesInPracticeClosures.aspx