# PowerShell: Links to interesting sites or blog posts

Tags: powershell

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831955/) [Alan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156862/) posted links to interesting pages about PowerShell. I found also some interesting pages:

- http://channel9.msdn.com/wiki/windowspowershellquickstart/ (cheatsheet)
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978525.aspx (core reference)
- http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/Joe/archive/2009/01/05/powershell-abcs---k-is-for-keywords.aspx (listing keywords)
- http://bsonposh.com/archives/327 (foreach vs. foreach-object)
- http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/ (book)

Do you know any interesting sites, blog posts, scripts, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yesterday I saw this list: http://blogs.technet.com/benp/archive/2009/12/02/powershell-resources.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Check out Shay Levy's one-stop shopping for good PowerShell links via his [PowerShell Toolbar for Internet Explorer](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/scriptfanatic/archive/2008/06/29/powershell-at-the-tip-of-your-browser.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

[PowerShellPack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/powershellpack), a set of Windows PowerShell V2 modules that allows you to do such nifty things as:

- Automate Task Scheduler
- Scripted UI in WPF
- Manage RSS feeds
- Manage photos

Answer (score 2):

Some links that I use relating to PowerShell.

- [PowerShell.com](http://powershell.com/cs/) - Sign up to the newsletter or follow them on Twitter as they do give out some useful tips daily.
- [A good introduction to PowerShell](http://webmat.wordpress.com/discover-powershell/)
- [PowerScripting](http://powerscripting.wordpress.com/) - a podcast on PowerShell
- [PowerShell team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/PowerShell/)
- [Keith's site](http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/)
- If your an app dev I'd recommend [PSake](http://codebetter.com/blogs/james.kovacs/archive/2009/10/14/releasing-psake-v1-00-amp-psake-v2-00.aspx)
- [PowerShell Gadget](http://andrewpeters.net/powershell-gadget/)
- [PowerShell Glass](http://powershellglass.codeplex.com/) - makes your PowerShell and cmd windows transparent

Two good free books for download are:

- [Mastering PowerShell](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/)
- [Effective PowerShell](http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!6930.entry)

Comment: You dont mention Powershell In Action, probably intentionally. Its definitely worthy of a mention at least - its a great book to explain PS (but I'm a dev so I would say that)

Comment: Yeah it is a great book, the books I did list are free pdf's that people can download.